# Calculate height of a paragraph and break it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, paragraph

i would like to insert inside a paragraph an html element every 200px of height, in order to break it.
Here is the paragraph:

```
<div class="newspaper">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla 
facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend o
ption congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
</div>

.newspaper p {
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Inside the paragraph i want to inject a span tag, like this:

```
<div class="newspaper">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
<span>TEST</span>
 Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla 
<span>TEST</span>facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
</div>
```

This is what i tried to do:

```
var height = $('.newspaper').height();
console.log(height);
if (height > 200) {
$( ".newspaper p" ).append( "</p><span>TEST</span><p>" );
}
```

The problem is that "append" inserts the html at the end.
I want it to loop every 200px of the paragraph height.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no way to just get 200 pixel intervals on a paragraph, you could manually set the blocks to 200px tall elements, and write a method to split a block of text into N character blocks (N being a good number to cover a 200px element)

```js
var fullParagraph = `...`;
var N = 10; //N. chars in 1 chunk, used in a string slicing fn.

var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");

var TEST = document.createElement("span");
TEST.innerHTML = "TEST";

var iterations = Math.floor(fullParagraph.length / N);

for(let i = 0; i < iterations; i++){

//Push your paragraph bit
let 200px_H_p = document.createElement("p");
const newContent = document.createTextNode( fullParagraph.slice(i * N, (i+1)*N );
200px_H_p .appendChild(newContent);



//Now I know the element above the insertion is 200px for sure, so put TEST after it


parentDiv.appendChild(200px_H_p);
parentDiv.appendChild(TEST);

}
```

Basically I just split a string into N-sized chunks of chars, then I just push them to the parent Div in intervals with your filler (in-between elements)

Comment: thanks a lot in advance, i wonder if it will work as the text is dynamically inserted in php

Comment: If php sends back a template (Like HTML pages already filled out), look for an id or class for the paragraph element, and just pull in the innerHTML as your `fullParagraph` string (using DOM), something like `var str = document.getElementsByClassName("newspaper_p")[0].innerHTML`

Comment: many thanks, unfortunately it doesn't work, surely I'm wrong in something: https://codepen.io/Mwww_/pen/JjBxxgV

Comment: Don't forget to `document.write(parentDiv);` at the bottom of your function since you've created the element, but still haven't added it to any interfaces.